# How to pass startup args for my app?

Tags: heroku, go

I want to pass startup arguments in my app so I can tell the application to load in either DEV or PROD settings.

How can I do this on heroku?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv ?

Comment: Take a look at the [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) buildin.

Comment: @elithrar I'm referring to how to give args to heroku when it starts up the app.

Comment: "heroku env vars" => https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 1):

First declare ENV variables in Heroku, ie:
`heroku config:set APPMODE=PROD`
then in you app, import the os package and call Getenv.
Example:

```
package main

import 'os'

var appmode string
func init () {
   appmode = os.Getenv("APPMODE") // PROD
}
```

Other option, using the flag package.
Example:

```
// flagsoverflow
package main

import "flag"

var AppMode string 

func init () {
   AppMode = flag.String("appmode", "DEV", "help message for flagname") // Defaul Value DEV
}

Then when u build u application u can run with flag options:

./flagsoverflow -appmode=PROD // Set the Value to PROD
```

Refs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

os: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv

Flags: https://golang.org/pkg/flag/